# pdo LIKE not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

my code here is part of a jquery ajax call and returns all results in the database instead of only items LIKE what i have entered and I cant see why, any suggestions?

```
$lname = '%'.$_POST['lname'].'%';   

$database->query("SELECT * FROM cust WHERE org_id = :org_id AND lname LIKE :lname");
$database->bind(':lname',$lname);
$database->bind(':org_id',$_SESSION['org_id']);
$existing = $database->resultset();
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: you mean it returns all `ord_id = ...` rows, regardless of the lname? Did you confirm that $_POSt['lname'] contains what you think it does?

Comment: mark, yes thats correct, it returns all org_id entries and ignores the LIKE part. If i change LIKE to = (and remove the % signs) it all appears to be working. I have also manually entered a name that is in the dbase ie AND lname LIKE '%smith%' and this works a treat.

Comment: **Did you confirm that `$_POST['lname']` contains what you think it does?**

Comment: yes i can confirm that it does, i have tested and im getting back smith initially then %smith% when im inside the php code.

Comment: @DeanHaines Can you show the row you want to get of **cust** table in the question ? I mean include some sample rows of the table on the question.

Comment: @Subin the table includes

    fname   lname
    james smith
    rick jones
    darren wilkes
    ryan wilkinson



i want to search for %wil%

and have it return 

    darren wilkes
    ryan wilkinson

is this what you were after?

Comment: but as i mentioned, its just handing back everything, ie  james smith, rick jones, darren wilkes, ryan wilkinson

Comment: @Deano Let's move this discussion over to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40125/q-pdo-like-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this one sorted, in the PHP file I needed this line adding just before the echo:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
```

Thanks everyone for your efforts

Comment: Other users would have got the answer if you explained the code and question better.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can't directly execute a code from a **PDO** connection
   variable.
2. It's **bindParam** not **bind**
3. There is no "resultset" function in **PDO**
4. To append values using **bindParam** you must need to wrap the
   **SQL** code in **PDO prepare** function.

Overall the code should be :

```
$lname = '%'.$_POST['lname'].'%';   
$sql=$database->prepare("SELECT * FROM cust WHERE org_id = :org_id AND lname LIKE :lname");
$sql->bindParam(':lname',$lname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(':org_id',$_SESSION['org_id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute();
$existing=$sql->fetch();//Resultset
```

in which **$database** is a valid **PDO** Connection.

Comment: I am growing to think that your age is no more an excuse for the hasty and pointless answers.

Comment: If you're going to change only one minor and pointless thing but otherwise just repost the OP's code, then at least point out WHERE you made that minor change...

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned that im using this class here   http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/  i know that the connections work because im using them in numerouse places thorughout the project already. thanks for your help though on this